# Fedora, Firefox and gnome shell extensions not working

Tags: fedora, firefox, gnome-shell

My gnome shell extension suddenly broke and doesn't allow me to either see installed extensions or install new ones. Every page has a 'An expected error occurred' message in the beginning.

Here's my journal grepping with firefox. Also, I'm using firejail. Might that be the cause?

```
    Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora systemd[2135]: app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope: unit configures an IP firewall, but not running as root.
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora systemd[2135]: app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope: (This warning is only shown for the first unit using IP firewalling.)
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-usr-share-common.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora systemd[2135]: Started app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-exec.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora systemd[2135]: Started cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope.service.
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-proc.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-run-common.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-runuser-common.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Parent pid 3307, child pid 3315
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3315]: Warning: An abstract unix socket for session D-BUS might still be available. Use --net or remove unix from --protocol set.
Dec 18 10:31:46 fedora firefox.desktop[3319]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:31:47 fedora firefox.desktop[3320]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:31:47 fedora firefox.desktop[3321]: Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Dec 18 10:31:47 fedora firefox.desktop[3315]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:31:47 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: Child process initialized in 183.79 ms
Dec 18 10:31:49 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: [Parent 8, Main Thread] WARNING: Failed to call GetIdletime(): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Dec 18 10:31:49 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: : 'glib warning', file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-120.0.1/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:187
Dec 18 10:31:49 fedora firefox[3323]: Failed to call GetIdletime(): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Dec 18 10:33:23 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (as)
Dec 18 10:33:24 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (asas)
Dec 18 10:33:34 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (as)
Dec 18 10:33:34 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (asas)
Dec 18 10:33:39 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (as)
Dec 18 10:33:39 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (as)
Dec 18 10:33:40 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (asas)
Dec 18 10:33:41 fedora firefox.desktop[3323]: (as)
Dec 18 10:35:37 fedora systemd[2135]: Stopping cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope.service...
Dec 18 10:35:37 fedora systemd[2135]: Stopped cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope.service.
Dec 18 10:35:37 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Parent received signal 15, shutting down the child process...
Dec 18 10:35:37 fedora systemd[2135]: Stopping app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell...
Dec 18 10:35:37 fedora firefox.desktop[3315]: Child received signal 15, shutting down the sandbox...
Dec 18 10:35:38 fedora firefox.desktop[3307]: Parent is shutting down, bye...
Dec 18 10:35:38 fedora systemd[2135]: Stopped app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
Dec 18 10:35:38 fedora systemd[2135]: app-gnome-firefox-3307.scope: Consumed 1min 20.519s CPU time.
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora systemd[1974]: app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope: unit configures an IP firewall, but not running as root.
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora systemd[1974]: app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope: (This warning is only shown for the first unit using IP firewalling.)
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-usr-share-common.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-exec.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-proc.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora systemd[1974]: Started app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-run-common.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-runuser-common.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora systemd[1974]: Started cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope.service.
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Parent pid 3216, child pid 3223
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3223]: Warning: An abstract unix socket for session D-BUS might still be available. Use --net or remove unix from --protocol set.
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3228]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3229]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3230]: Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3223]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:36:25 fedora firefox.desktop[3232]: Child process initialized in 127.48 ms
Dec 18 10:36:32 fedora firefox.desktop[3232]: [Parent 8, Main Thread] WARNING: Failed to call GetIdletime(): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Dec 18 10:36:32 fedora firefox.desktop[3232]: : 'glib warning', file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-120.0.1/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:187
Dec 18 10:36:32 fedora firefox[3232]: Failed to call GetIdletime(): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[3216]: Parent is shutting down, bye...
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora systemd[1974]: app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope: Consumed 4min 36.469s CPU time.
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora systemd[1974]: Stopping cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope.service...
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora systemd[1974]: Stopped cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-3216.scope.service.
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-usr-share-common.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-exec.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-proc.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-run-common.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora systemd[1974]: Started app-gnome-firefox-5524.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-runuser-common.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora systemd[1974]: Started cgroupify@app-gnome-firefox-5524.scope.service.
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5524]: Parent pid 5524, child pid 5531
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5531]: Warning: An abstract unix socket for session D-BUS might still be available. Use --net or remove unix from --protocol set.
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5535]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5536]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5537]: Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5531]: Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Dec 18 10:50:44 fedora firefox.desktop[5539]: Child process initialized in 189.36 ms
Dec 18 10:50:51 fedora firefox.desktop[5539]: [Parent 7, Main Thread] WARNING: Failed to call GetIdletime(): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
Dec 18 10:50:51 fedora firefox.desktop[5539]: : 'glib warning', file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-120.0.1/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:187
Dec 18 10:50:51 fedora firefox[5539]: Failed to call GetIdletime(): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown
```

Thanks!